# Trouble Understanding Government's Financial Databases

Tags: united-states, public-funding, illinois

What does these codes mean on Illinois's financial data found in https://illinoiscomptroller.gov/constituent-services/local-government/local-government-division/financial-databases/

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting some official in Illinois? They might know best (just in case nobody else here knows). Maybe the [comptrollers office](https://illinoiscomptroller.gov/about/contact-us/phone-mailing-addresses)?

Comment: @Trilarion Do you think they would reply my email in a few days? I worry that it may take months for them to get to it 

Comment: I have no idea about how long they would take. But I know that an email is quickly written and that they definitely won't reply to an inquiry that was never sent. And also here it might take longer.

Comment: i found a breakdown two clicks into your link : https://illinoiscomptroller.gov/ioc-pdf/LocalGovt/AFR2019/2019ChartofAccounts.pdf  page 7+